# Run multiple script in ubuntu server

Tags: python, bash, shell

i have 7 `py` files which has to run continuously. These `py` scripts are in different locations. I am running these files like `watch -n 2 ./myscript.py`. Is there a way where i can create one bash file or something similar which runs all my 7 `py` script parallel? So i can start one script

Comment: python script1.py & <newline>
python script2.py & (basically we send it to background)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to run multiple Python files in // is to tell each process to go into the background with the & shell operator.

```sh
    python script1.py &
    python script2.py &
    python script3.py &
    .......
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
    
for folder_name in Fol1 Fol2 F3 F4 floderX
do
cd $folder_name

# run any command in the folder
        
    cd ..  #back to main folder
    
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have just put a comment to Aditya answer if I had enough reputation but if you want to run in parallel and still use watch, you can also do (assuming you have a shebang in your scripts giving the right python interpreter):

```
watch 'pathto/script1.py & pathto/script2.py & pathto/script3.py &'
```

(maybe you can also think of adding those scripts to your $PYTHONPATH to avoid giving the path to the scripts)